# Javascript Progres bar unsyncs with page scroll

Tags: javascript

I'm building a progress bar for an e-commerce shop. I want the progress bar to follow the page scroll but in the position where it is. So far I haven't been able to find the correct values.

```
<script>
      console.log('num. steps: '+howManytabs);
      
      window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

      function myFunction() {
        var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 65;
        if (scrolled > 45){
          var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 80
        }
        if (scrolled > 77){
          var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100
        }
        document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
      }
    </script>



<div class="progress-header">
          <div class="progress-container">
            <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
          </div> 
        </div>

   

    .progress-header {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.progress-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.progress-bar {
    height: 8px;
    width: 0%;
```

(The progress is starting to soon and then it speeds up on the second phase, then slows down again and last it speeds up on the "charger" phase.)

[progress bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Poj2V.jpg)

Can somebody help and give me some hints?

Comment: We're probably going to need to see your HTML as well

Comment: Thank you @lucasvw

Comment: It seems that the problem was in scrolled variable. I just deleted the first two steps, that measured the size of the page that was scrolled down. (winScroll / height) * 100 just hit the spot. Easy and smooth progress bar! Thank you @lucasvw